# What is the proper way to show different elements based on function return

Tags: html, angular

So basically what I want is to show

1. 'Something1' when the job is not processing
2. 'Something2' when the job is running and status is '0'
3. 'Something3' when the job is running but status is something else

I tried the following code snippet, but it looks like let-status in the outer template will never get assigned. Not sure whether the implementation is correct or not, could anyone give me two cents on how to make this logic work?

Thanks.

```
<span *ngIf="!isProcessing(); else elseBlock">
        Something1
</span>
<ng-template #elseBlock let-status="queryPlaybackStatus()" *ngIf="queryStatus() === '0'; else innerElseBlock">
    <span>
        Something2
    </span>
    <ng-template #innerElseBlock>
        <span>
            Something3
        </span>
    </ng-template>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<span *ngIf="!isProcessing(); else elseBlock">
        Something1
</span>
<ng-container #elseBlock *ngIf="queryStatus() as status">
    <span *ngIf="status === '0'; else innerElseBlock">
            Something2
    </span>
    <ng-template #innerElseBlock>
        <span>
            Something3_with_{{status}}%
        </span>
    </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

So basically this need a magic combination of ng-container and ng-template.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest defining a string in your component, where you have much better control over your logic. In the component, set the string to the appropriate text.

Then bind to that string in the template.

I don't have all of your needed logic here, but something like this:

```
  isImage = false;

  get statusText(): string {
    if (!isProcessing()) {
      this.isImage = false;
      return 'Something1';
    } else {
      this.isImage = true;
      return 'path to image';
    }
  }
```

This uses a getter, which provides a way for a component property to have logic.

Then just bind to `statusText` in the template.

```
<span *ngIf='!isImage'>
        {{statusText}}
</span>
<span *ngIf='isImage>
    <img ...>
</span>
```

Comment: well, this is a good idea for pure text, but in my case, something could be text or image, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want [ngSwitch](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch). This allows you to switch based on logic, which you should encapsulate in your component, not your template. First, let's create a property that encapsulates our logic in our component:

```
public get currentStep(): number {
  if (!this.isProcessing) {
    return 1;
  } else if (this.queryStatus === 0) {
    return 2;
  } else {
    return 3;
  }
}
```

Next, let's bind our `ngSwitch` statement to this newly-created property:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="currentStep">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="1">
        <p>Something1</p>
        <div>Put whatever you want in here! Images, etc.</div>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="2">
        <p>Something2</p>
        <p>Loading....</p>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="3">
        <p>Something3</p>
        <p>All done!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

That should get you where you need to go. Since this is simple, I [created a stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cgeasa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) that will demonstrate a working version of this. In the example, you can click a button and watch the app cycle through all the steps (I'm using `setTimeout` to simulate a long-running server query).